# Await only for some time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

So waiting for server can bring pain:

```
    import asyncio 
    #...
    greeting = await websocket.recv() # newer ends
```

I want to have something like

```
    greeting = await websocket.recv() for seconds(10)
```

So how to await only for a limited amount of time in Python?

Comment: Check the documentation. Does this method take a timeout parameter?

Comment: I wonder about await sintax, not a particular method

Comment: What is `websocket`? You can do `greeting = yield from asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=10)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[await expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#await) don't have a timeout parameter, but the [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=wait_for#asyncio.wait_for) (thanks to AChampion) function does. My guess is that this is so that the await expression, tied to coroutine definition in the language itself, does not rely on having clocks or a specific event loop. That functionality is left to the asyncio module of the standard library.

Comment: the default `await` keyword used with asyncio has built-in timeout somehow, i can see `TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`. Code line `File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 714`

Comment: That is a network stack (OS) level error in connect, not await aborting the connection.

Answer (score 5):

There's actually an official way to accomplish a timeout for a co-routine without any hacking.

It's described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=wait_for#asyncio.timeout

```py
try:
    async with asyncio.timeout(10):
        result=await long_running_task()
except TimeoutError:
    print("The long operation timed out, but we've handled it.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in a `try:` `except:` block,

```py
time_seconds = 60
try:
    result = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=time_seconds)
    print(result)
    
except Exception as e:
    if str(type(e)) == "<class 'asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError'>": 
        print('specifically a asyncio TimeoutError') 
    else:
        Print('different error:', e)
```

if the timeout occurs before the message is received, then one gets a `TimeoutError` error.

The timeout error is this:

```
<class 'asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError'>
```

which you can then handle differently from other genuine errors.

Comment: This is the wrong way to differentiate between exceptions. The correct way would be to `except TimeoutError` (as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for)), optionally followed by other except blocks. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Comment: @14mRh4X0r,  this was a method that was succesful for me at the time, so i posted it as an answer because it simply works. Outside to pointing to generic documentation (i actually generated the idea from the same docs), i too would be most interested in a better solution **as a practical answer** as opposed to a downvote.